# Как работает $resource в angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть такой сервис:

```
function fileManagerClient($resource, $http, $rootScope, dataService) {
    var userId = $rootScope.globals.currentUser.userId;
    var kpeId = $rootScope.kpeId;
    var fileName = "8888";
    return $resource("api/file/:userId/:kpeId/:fileName",
            { fileName: "@fileName" },
            {
                'query': { method: 'GET', params: { userId: '@userId', kpeId: '@kpeId', fileName: fileName } },
                'save': { method: 'POST', params: { userId: userId, kpeId: kpeId, fileName: fileName }, transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } },
                'remove': { method: 'DELETE', params: { userId: userId, kpeId: kpeId, fileName: fileName } }
            });
}
```

И есть другой сервис, который вызывает методы query, save, remove сервиса fileManagerClient.

Когда я захожу на страницу, вызывается метод query. Отрабатывает метод в WebApi и получаю ошибку

> [result: [$resource:badcfg] query
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object&p2=GET&p3=api%2Ffile%2F8e845a58-2bca-4879-8cde-7ce90b49490c%2Ffe90aad5-55ea-4f23-baeb-f66afd387e45%2Ftest](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object&p2=GET&p3=api%2Ffile%2F8e845a58-2bca-4879-8cde-7ce90b49490c%2Ffe90aad5-55ea-4f23-baeb-f66afd387e45%2Ftest)

Как настроить `$resource`, чтобы отрабатывали все методы(query, save, remove)?

Comment: не, все очень плохо. убирай твои load и remove, и добавь серверный метод который по query Должен вызываться

Comment: зачем он здесь?

Comment: чтобы было видно что именно ты в него возвращаешь. Сейчас ты сказал что у тебя ошибка потому что ты возвращаешь объект. А в ответе еще раз сказал ждать массив

Comment: Забей. В моем случае возвращается объект, и в коде у меня стоит `isArray: false`. Сейчас изменю ответ. Просто в качестве правильного ответа здесь по-моему это не принципиально. Там даже в тексте ошибки говориться ожидается массив а пришел объект, либо наоборот.

Comment: Это как раз принципиально, что в ошибке говорится, что пришел объект, а ты ждешь массив. А в ответе ты пишешь, что типа - теперь я точно жду массив :-) то есть вообще непонятно что именно решилось

Comment: Я не понял. В тексте ошибки на сайте angularjs говориться что ожидается массив а пришел объект либо наоборот. **or vice versa** - или наоборот

Comment: _В тексте ошибки на сайте angularjs говориться что ожидается массив а пришел объект_ - то есть ангуляр ждет массив, это значит что у него уже стоит флаг _isArray_

Comment: Ну так я его и поставил в `false`, т.к. у меня объект. Теперь он ожидает объект и я его ему даю

Comment: Именно! но в ответе ты сначала сказал, что надо поставить true, при этом поставив false, потом поставил везде true, потом false, потом опять true. И вот только сейчас false.

Comment: Да это было временное помешательство, так делать не надо было)

Comment: Да, так явно лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пройдя по ссылке в тексте ошибки, я понял что сервис `$resource` в качестве ответа ожидает объект, а у меня возвращался массив.

Решение: в метод `'query'` добавить параметр `isArray: false`

Окончательный вариант: `'query': { method: 'GET', params: { userId: '@userId', kpeId: '@kpeId', fileName: fileName }, isArray: false}`

Всё заработало как надо.

Comment: `добавить параметр isArray: true`, _Окончательный вариант: `isArray: false`_ :) ты уж определись

Comment: не угадал :-) у тебя же сервер объект возвращает!

Comment: теперь правильно?)

Comment: Ну это же твой код :-D просто скопируй с настоящего кода как ты сделал.